# Can't find NAB Transact Hosted Payment Page (HPP) test URL

Tags: payment, gateway

NAB Transact Payment URL for testing purposes "https://transact.nab.com.au/test/hpp/payment", is no longer working. It probably have been changed into some other link. But I can't seem to find it anywhere, and the documentation has old URL. Please help if anyone worked on this

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

The URL for test mode is "https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/live/hpp/payment"